# df.corr showing all data as 1 when read from compiled csv, even though there is data that is different

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a compiled data frame of sp500 stock data that I am trying to find correlations with using `df.corr()`, but it is labeling all data as having a '1' correlation when I run the program, and when I use a heat map to visualize the data it shows an entire green chart, when there should be many many different positive and negative correlations.

Using Python 3.6 and Spyder

here is the code I am using:

```
def visualize_data():
df = pd.read_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format
#df['AAPL'].plot()
#plt.show()
df_corr = df.corr() #creates a correlation table of our data frame.  Generates correlation values       
print(df_corr.head())

data1 = df_corr.values #gets inner values of our data frame 
fig1 = plt.figure() #specify our figures
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1) #defined axis 1 by 1 plot 1

heatmap1 = ax1.pcolor(data1, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlGn) #sets the color paramater of heat map (negative,neutral,positive)
fig1.colorbar(heatmap1)
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(data1.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False) #sets x ticks for heat map, arranging ticks at every 0.5(half-mark)
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(data1.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False) #sets y ticks for heat map
ax1.invert_yaxis() #removes random gap from the top of graph
ax1.xaxis.tick_top() #moves x axis ticks to the top (meant to look more like a table)

column_labels = df_corr.columns
row_labels = df_corr.index

ax1.set_xticklabels(column_labels)
ax1.set_yticklabels(row_labels)

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
heatmap1.set_clim(-1,1)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.savefig("correlations.png", dpi = (300))
plt.show()
```

visualize_data()

The interesting thing is that I searched all over for anyone having a similar error, and I cannot seem to find any answers.  Could it be that the ticker symbols could be considered categorical and therefore something is getting skewed?  I'm not quite sure here, to be honest.

Even when I tried to plot the correlations for one single company against all the data as seen by `#df['AAPL'].plot()` and `#plt.show()` the same exact thing happened where the data is only registering a correlation value of `1.0000` to all of the data.

I initially thought it was a rounding error due to significant figures, so I put in `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format` but that didn't work and i still am receiving the skewed correlation.

[Here is a screenshot of the issue and the subsequent heat map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnFOZ.png)

[Here is a screenshot of part of the data, confirming that it isn't all the same or that is has become corrupted in some measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UcH0.png)

Comment: All of your columns in the screenshot you shared are exactly the same as one another, how can you expect to have variation in correlation? That is the answer to your question. Side note: A good practice is to avoid spaghetti code, and to take the entire code out of the big function first. Next test your df_corr on a sample of 10-20 lines of your data and make sure you are calculating the correlation right. Then add the visulatization on top of it gradually, and convert the whole thing to a function at the very end.

Comment: Yes, I do see that now.  I will figure out what went wrong.  Thank you

Comment: Cool. Other than that issue, nothing seems wrong at the first sight. But please try and follow the simple-to-complicated approach, which lets you find bugs more easily.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with sourcing the data through the google finance api.  There seemed to have been an error downloading one of the dates to one of the sp500 companies and when I compiled all of the data including those few missing dates it could only produce one line of data for some reason.  This lead to a correlation of '1' since all the data was exactly the same.  I found the specific dates and added them in manually and now the program runs as it should.  Thank you.